# how do I pass in arguments for connect logger?

Tags: logging, node.js, express, connect

This is a basic question but I'm not sure what the syntax is for passing in the stream option to the arguments in connect logger middleware.

http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-logger.html

Is it?:

```
connect.logger('default', myLogger)
```

And if I wanted to log it to loggly, would I pass in the Loggly object?   What interface would it have to implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok figured it out..

```
connect.logger(format: 'short', stream:Logger)
```

And in the Logger object implement a method called "write"

```
exports.write = (msg) ->
    process.stdout.write msg
```